# Tower of Hanoi ordered numbers

Tags: towers-of-hanoi

Tower of Hanoi problem is how do I implement the following?
please help me !

http://imageupload.co.uk/files/qpxsdyyxtbl5ik38zcn0.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know using which language you want to implement this. But you can implement this using stack.

Suppose you have 3 pegs 1,2,3 and 3 disks A,B,C. You can implement it as follows:-

```
         A -> 3                  
         A -> 2
         C -> 2
         A -> 3
         B -> 1
         B -> 3
         A -> 3
```

You can refer to this link(http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/13/hanoi.html) for more detailed solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Please note : http://imageupload.co.uk/files/qpxsdyyxtbl5ik38zcn0.jpg